# What is the index of nilpotency of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

Here is the question I am trying to answer:

Find the Jordan form of
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that the first step is to find the eigenvalues, which I did and I found them to be $\lambda = 0,1,-1.$ I know that by a theorem we know that $A - \lambda I $ is a nilpotent matrix, but when I tried to compute the index of nilpotency incase of $\lambda = 0$ i.e., of  the given matrix $A$ I kept on multiplying now until the 5th time but it is still not giving me zero, I am wondering if someone can clarify this to me, is my matrix $A$ contains a typo? if not, what is its index of nilpotency?

Comment: For an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent if and only if $\lambda$ is the **only** eigenvalue of $A$, so your assertion that $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent is not true. What is true is that the *restriction* of $A-\lambda I$ to the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ is nilpotent.

Comment: So what should be my next step in calculating the JCF in this case?@ArturoMagidin

Comment: This matrix is $3\times 3$ and has three distinct eigenvalues. It is diagonalizable, so you should know immediately what the JCF of $A$ is, no need for further calculations. As to the general case, there are several algorithms (recipes) for figuring out the JCF; I don't know which one you learned/were taught.

Comment: Ok, so the JCF of this matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ am I correct? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Up to reordering the blocks, yes.

Comment: I think the ordering of the blocks does not matter because all of them of size one (if my understanding is correct), right? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Matrices have multiple Jordan Canonical forms, unless there is a single block, or the matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity. Why isn't $\left(\begin{array}{rcc}-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ *also* a Jordan Canonical form for $A$?  Answer: it **is**. Jordan Canonical Forms are only unique *up to the ordering of the blocks*, just like diagonal forms (when they exist) are only unique up to the order of the diagonal entries.